# Get array values using index key in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, key-value

I'm iterating through an array or hash, and I'd like to get values based on index.

```
@lv = {'apple' => ['round', 'red'], 'more names' => ['tags', 'more tags']}

@lv.each do |key, value|
   # if the value is from the index key and equal to key itself...
end
```

I'm not sure how to get the value from `@lv`. Lets say I want to get `apple`:

Is there something like `@lv[0]` should equal apple? Because

```
[0] => apple
[1] => more names
```

right?

So I can

```
@lv.each do |key, value|
   if @lv[0] == key
     # apple equals apple, then proceed
   end
end
```

What is the correct syntax on doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@lv.keys[0]   # => "apple"
@lv.values[0] # => ["round", "red"]
```